# Encoding string in PHP

Tags: php

I currently working on PHP and at some part of code I generate URL string. I set the GET parameter to  `currencyCode`. But before I add `&`. So, at result I must get `&currencyCode` but get `¤cyCode`.

How do I fix it?

Comment: Take a look at [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create url this way using `urlencode()` function:

```
<?php

   echo 'http://example.com/'.urlencode('&currencyCode');
```

I also think that your main problem is with displaying it. You should use:

```
echo htmlspecialchars('&currencyCode');
```

to display it.

Otherwise it seems browser change the first part of this string into: `&curren;` entity so you get something like that `&curren;cyCode` and what makes you have display `&curren;` symbol what is `¤` and the rest of string `cyCode`

Answer (score 1):

You should use `urlencode()` function in php to encode the url. Your code should look like this

```
<?php
echo 'http://yoursitename.com/'.urlencode('&currencyCode');
```